# How to search for text in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to create a script that checks the stock of items on a website, im trying to locate every line that has "ATS" in it including the number after the colon. I then want to print all the values of "ATS" (one value for each size) Here is the script that I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

prodpage=requests.get('http://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/Product-GetVariants?pid=S32145', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} )

soup = BeautifulSoup(prodpage.text)

print (soup)
```

**which returns this:**

```
{"id": "S32145_590", "attributes": {
"size":"7"
},
"articleNo": "S32145",
"onlineFrom": 1.4667516E12,
"customBadges": "~",
"pricing": {"standard": "140.0", "sale": "140.0", "isPromoPrice": false, "quantities": [
{"unit": "PIECE", "value": "1.0"}
]}
,
"avStatusQuantity": 1.0,
"avStatus": "IN_STOCK",
"inStock": true,
"avLevels": {"IN_STOCK": 1.0,
"PREORDER": 0.0,
"BACKORDER": 0.0,
"NOT_AVAILABLE": 0.0,
"PREVIEW": 0.0},
"ATS": 7.0,
"inStockDate": ""
},
```

Comment: Try changing this: `soup = BeautifulSoup(prodpage.text, "html.parser")`, it's not an answer to your question but newer python 3 versions ask for it

Answer (score 0):

I think BeautifulSoup is not the optimal way to go. It looks more like json-formated data. BeautifulSoup is mainly a parser for HTML/XML.
So my suggestion is to go for

```
import requests
import json

prodpage=requests.get('http://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/Product-GetVariants?pid=S32145', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} )
data = json.loads(prodpage.text)
```

and then looking for ATS in the dict structure i.e.

```
for variant in data['variations']['variants']:
   print(variant['ATS'])
```

This returns for me

```
0
0
12.0
0
8.0
0
7.0
0.0
6.0
0.0
17.0
12.0
18.0
2.0
9.0
3.0
7.0
0
7.0
0
5.0
```

Comment: Hi TPerry

Nice to hear that, so can you please mark it as solved! Thanks!